# Reverse intersect in Postgres sql two tables

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have two A and B queries with output with same fields.

Now I need to merge missing records from B to A.
There are 5 fields with the same name but the last field have the difference in values.

I can not perform except because each last field from B is having a different value that last field in A.

How can I perform merge?

For merging, I need to put the condition on two fields only.

Please take a look at below images.

Sample inputs:

Query A

```
Id | Name | count 
1  | Test | 3
2  | Test1 | 2
```

Query B

```
Id | Name | count 
1  | Test | 0
2  | Test1 | 0
3  | Test2 | 0
4  | Test3 | 0
```

The result should be based on column Id and Name

Expected result:

```
Id | Name | count 
1  | Test | 3
2  | Test1 | 2
3  | Test2 | 0
4  | Test3 | 0
```

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will keep in mind posting dummy data here afterwords.

Answer (score 1):

Use `full join` and [`coalesce():`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)

```
with query_a(id, name, count) as (
values
    (1, 'Test', 3),
    (2, 'Test1', 2)
),
query_b(id, name, count) as (
values
    (1, 'Test', 0),
    (2, 'Test1', 0),
    (3, 'Test2', 0),
    (4, 'Test3', 0)
)
select id, name, coalesce(a.count, b.count) as count
from query_a a
full join query_b b using(id, name)

 id | name  | count 
----+-------+-------
  1 | Test  |     3
  2 | Test1 |     2
  3 | Test2 |     0
  4 | Test3 |     0
(4 rows)
```